# How to make app link work for facebook for android only with open graph stroy

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph, applinks

I have an android only app. It has a feature to share an open graph story in facebook. I have managed that part. Now I want app link integration between my app and facebook. But the documention in facebook is very confusing. I also tried the app link host tool and created the app link from [web-based App Links tool](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host)  When i tried to open it from my android phone it says

> This is only available from via the `MyAppName` app. Do you want to install it from the Play Store?

but my app is already installed. Below is the code i used to share.

```
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "mynamespace:post")
            .putString("og:title", title)
            .putString("og:description", description)
            .putString("og:url","link provided by  api link tool")
            .putString("al:android:url","myapp://abc/123")
            .putString("al:android:app_name",getString(R.string.app_name))
            .putString("al:android:package","com.myapp")
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("mynamespace:share")
            .putObject("post", object)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("post")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

mShareDialog.show(content);
```

I dont want to use other libraries like branch.io or parse cloud service.

> NOTE The app is in development mode